# Generate Factory in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, factory, laravel-5.5

I ran below command

`php artisan make:factory AddressFactory`

I am getting below result

`$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {`

But I would like to get result like below

`$factory->define(App\Address::class, function (Faker $faker) {`

What should I do ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#generating-factories

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the **make:factory** command to generate a factory class for an existing model, you need to tell it which model to use with the **--model** option:

```
php artisan make:factory AddressFactory --model="App\\Address"
```

Comment: I think we should use "\" instead of "\\"

Comment: @PhanVanLinh you need to escape "\" in bash command line if you want it to be passed to the PHP command, hence the "\\"

Answer (score 1):

### For Laravel 8

With the artisan command, you no longer need to specify the model. By automatically including the factory trait in the model, Laravel automatically makes the factory methods available to the corresponding model.

**So only:**

`php artisan make:factory AddressFactory`

It is then sufficient to call the model in the seeder or in the tests.

**For example:**

`App\Models\Address::factory(10)->create();`

> Model & Factory Discovery Conventions
>
> Once you have defined your factories, you may use the static factory
> method provided to your models by the
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory trait in order to
> instantiate a factory instance for that model.
>
> The HasFactory trait's factory method will use conventions to
> determine the proper factory for the model the trait is assigned to.
> Specifically, the method will look for a factory in the
> Database\Factories namespace that has a class name matching the model
> name and is suffixed with Factory. If these conventions do not apply
> to your particular application or factory, you may overwrite the
> newFactory method on your model to return an instance of the model's
> corresponding factory directly:

Answer (score 0):

Using this command, you make a factory for specific table (eg.table-User)

```
php artisan make:factory UserFactory --model=User
```

After this, go to database/factor and open your UserFactor add fake data in your Definition function like this

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        return [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'password' => bcrypt('password'), // default password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
```

Don't forget to use `use Faker\Generator as Faker;`

After this you go to database/seeder and open DatabaseSeeder and add this In your run function

```
 User::factory()->count(10)->create();
```

At Last You need to seed your data to data using this command

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder
```

Change table name and data as your requirement thank you.